# Invalid prop `data` of type `number` supplied to `DataProvider`, expected `array`. React-bootstrap-table2, Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-bootstrap-table

I've been trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database and display it in react-bootstrap-table2, but I've run into some issues when it comes to actually displaying the data. When I run the code I get an error: *Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `number` supplied to `DataProvider`, expected `array`.*

Here is my code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const getTimestamp = () => {
    const database = db.ref("timestamped_measures");
    database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
      ts_measures.forEach((ts_measure) => {
        setTimestamp(ts_measure.val().timestamp);
      });
    });
  };

  const columns = [{ dataField: "timestamp", text: "Timestamp" }];
  useEffect(() => {
    getTimestamp();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="timestamp"
        data={timestamp}
        columns={columns}
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[This is what my Firebase database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cex9c.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
[console.log(timestamp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GqaN.png)
[console.log(typeof timestamp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSeHS.png)

Comment: Hi Nina, could you `console.log(timestamp)` and `console.log(typeof timestamp)` and paste it here?

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac Thanks for your reply. I have just added the screenshots of my console for those two commands. I noticed that the values weren't in an array, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your timestamp results from ts_measures into an array, and store it in state. I assume, since your columns contain a datafield "timestamp", each of your data rows would require this key which would hold the data for the TimeStamp column.

```
{timestamp: ts_measure.val().timestamp}
```

Give this a shot

```
const getTimestamp = () => {
  const database = db.ref("timestamped_measures");
  database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {
   setTimestamp(ts_measures.map((ts_measure) => {
      return {timestamp: ts_measure.val().timestamp}
    }));
  });
};
```

Comment: @Ganzdal Thank you! But when I changed the code it gave me an error: _TypeError: ts_measures.map is not a function_.

Comment: what data structure do you expect in ts_measures? what does it look like when you console log it? (console.log(ts_measures) before the return statement)

Comment: If I console.log(ts_measures) right before the return statement I don't get anything in the console. However, adding it before setTimestamp(..) (right after database.on("value", (ts_measures) => {) returns what can be seen in the screenshot I've just added above.

Comment: Follow this link to see the screenshot: https://imgur.com/UMLLGNK